# Java: How to reparse 'Array.toString' again in Array?

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

I have a array which I convert to string to use it as key  in an hashmap.
How is it possible to convert a string like this `[5.0, -1.0, 2.0]` again to an array consisting of three double values?

PS: I'm kind of new to java but I couldnt find a solution here or via google.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3272808/86515 combined with Double.parseDouble

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9101301/how-to-convert-string-array-to-double-array-in-one-line
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454137/java-converting-string-in-array-to-double

Try these.

Comment: Why not use a  `List<Double>` as the key in the hash map, rather than a `String`?  Trying to dump it into a `String` is definitely a code smell.

Comment: +1 for Louis' comment, but remember not to modify the list after you've started using it as a hash key. better yet, use an immutable list (like you'll find in the guava library)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible, with a bit of fiddling - and by the way, it's a very, very bad idea to use an array as a key to a `Map` (even if it's converted to a `String`), because it can change its contents. Try this:

```
String array = "[5.0, -1.0, 2.0]";
String[] data = array.substring(1, array.length()-1).split(", ");
double[] answer = new double[data.length];
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    answer[i] = Double.parseDouble(data[i]);
```

Now `answer` will be an array of doubles with the values originally contained in the `String`.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any ready method for this. So, you have to create your own method, which will parse your string back into array of double-s. You can do it, using `String.split(...)` method for example.

Answer (score 0):

See documentation for `String.substring()` and `String.split()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(stringToParse);
ArrayList<Double> buffer = new ArrayList<>();
while(sc.hasNextDouble())
    buffer.add(sc.nextDouble());
Object[] doubles = buffer.toArray();
```

Comment: the last line should be `Double[] doubles = buffer.toArray(new Double[buffer.size()])`

Comment: This answer returns a `Double[]`, OP was asking for a `double[]`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work

```
List<Double> yourDoubleList = new ArrayList<Double>();
String withoutBrackets = array.substring(1, array.length() - 1);
for(String number : withoutBrackets.split(",")) {
    yourDoubleList.add(Double.parseDouble(number));
}
```

Comment: This answer returns a `List<Double>`, OP was asking for a `double[]`

Comment: @ÓscarLópez yes, but arguably the list is still a better choice for usability (at least for a small number of doubles)